# App catalog - Site collection vs root site collection scope question

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, administration, app-catalog

I have a SPFx web part which I downloaded from [Images and Videos in a Carousel](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-carousel).

I don't have access to the root site collection app catalog so I added it to a site collection catalog I newly created. But I can't see the app appear on site pages after I uploaded it to the new site collection catalog (not the root site).

Does this matter?

Does it depends if the SPFx package was built for root site collection only?

Comment: Have you uploaded and **published/deployed** the spfx package in app catalog successfully? Check if there is any error. If everything is fine, you should see the SPFx web part on all pages in this site collection site and it's sub-sites.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just uploaded the sppkg to the site collection where i created the app catalog.Not the root site collection. Do  i need to use the tool chain to deply the sppkg package?

Comment: Not necessary, you can manually upload and publish/deploy the sppkg file. If there is any error in deploying the package it should show error message. If there is no error then it should work.

Comment: I don't seem to get the Deploy prompt when i upload it

Comment: Hi Ganesh, see  scrrenshot of error here https://ibb.co/7nKvZ2R

Comment: Try this with site collection administrator privileges on site collection app catalog site.

Comment: Tried it with Admin no luck :(

Comment: Doesn't prompt for deployment

Comment: Got it .You need to have access to the app catalog in the root site collection

Answer (score 1):

You can manually upload and publish/deploy the `.sppkg` file in any app catalog. If there is any error in deploying the package it should show error message in apps library. If there is no error then it should work on site collection.

Also, make sure you have **Site collection administrator** privileges on both the tenant level app catalog & site collection app catalog to deploy the package.